# Php routes does not change the effect in the browser bar

Tags: php, class, routes

This is my main **index** file I want that when I write in the browser about it loads the about page but it fails.

```
<?php


  $database = require 'core/bootstrap.php';


  require Router::load('routes.php')
    ->direct(Request::uri());

 ?>
```

This is my **routes.php file**

```
<?php

$router->define([

  '' => 'controllers/index.php',
  'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
  'about-culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
  'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);

?>
```

**This is my Router file**

```
<?php

  class Router
  {
    protected $routes = [];

    public static function load($file)
    {
      $router = new static;
      require $file;
      return $router;
    }

    public function define($routes)
    {
      $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri)
      {
          if(array_key_exists($uri , $this->routes))
          {
            return $this->routes[$uri];
          }
          throw new Exception('No Routes defined for this URL');
      }
  }
 ?>
```

I don`t know what is the error here, I tried a lot and also watch the tutorial and do exactly as he do but I fail to show the output.

```
require Router::load('routes.php')
        ->direct(Request::uri());
```

when I write only the start **localhost:8080/start/** (this is the folder where all my files are present , it gives me this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: No Routes defined for this URL in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\core\Router.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\start\index.php(8): Router->direct('start') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\core\Router.php on line 25**

and when I load page like about it says object not found.

Request class

```
<?php

class Request
{
  public static function uri()
  {
    return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump(Request::uri())` and see what it says. It probably says `start/` or similar which isn't in your list.

Comment: string(5) "start" this is the answer

Comment: which router library you are using?

Comment: There is no library included, Just these configurations but I don`t know the error

Comment: then where is implementaton of Request::uri()

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: no just core php

Answer (score 0):

Basically `REQUEST_URI` contains the whole url except hostname and protocol since start is your folder name and root directory of your application your have to get request uri after start

```
for eg
http://localhost/start/about/ 
REQUEST_URI = /start/about/
after trimming  = start/about
```

which will not match any router.
so you have to pass your base directory to your function somehow one way is to modify your uri function

```
class Request
{
  public static function uri($base = "")
  {
    $url =  str_replace($base,"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    return trim( $url , '/');
  }
}
```

and can be called as `Request::uri("start")`

Comment: I do not only want to show the index file, but it only displays that file and the links on the file don`t work. I don't want to hardcore these values I want to pass them in the browser baar.

Comment: I am not saying you to hardore url's  the passing parameter is your root directory for ex. your app resides in xampp/htdocs/dir1/dir2 then your root dir will 'dir1/dir2' which is hardcoded but after that about will be still dynamic @MuhammadHamza

Comment: But then why this don`t work, by replacing your change it displays the index page but on code runs on that page, no links are working, and even though when I write in the browser bar about, it give me object not found

Comment: I added the list above with ur ans

Comment: Your links are not working because your url is seen like http://localhost/about it should look like http://localhost/start/about either change your url or use base tag in html head section

Comment: or try removing beginning slash(/) from your url